# Horizontal 2d matrix transformation (scale) - JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, matrix, scaling

I have a 2d matrix like this example below:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00110000011000111111000110000000110000001111100000
00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000
00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000
00111111111000111111000110000000110000010000010000
00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000
00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000
00110000011000111111000111111000111111001111100000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

and I'd like to transform this matrix by scaling the matrix horizontally with a specific factor `(e.g 2.0 or 0.5, ...)` so that the matrix afterwards looks like this:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ...
00111100000000000111100000011111111111111000000111100000000000000 ...
00111100000000000111100000011110000000000000000111100000000000000 ...
00111100000000000111100000011110000000000000000111100000000000000 ...
00111111111111111111100000011111111111111000000111100000000000000 ...
00111100000000000111100000011110000000000000000111100000000000000 ...
00111100000000000111100000011110000000000000000111100000000000000 ...
00111100000000000111100000011111111111111000000111111111111110000 ...
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ...
```

or

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000
00100010011110010000010000001110000
00100010010000010000010000010001000
00100010010000010000010000010001000
00111110011110010000010000010001000
00100010010000010000010000010001000
00100010010000010000010000010001000
00100010011110011110011110001110000
00000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

My javascript "matrix" -`array`- looks like this:

```
var matrix = [
  '001000100001',
  '001111101100',
  '001111101100',
  '001000100001'
]
```

```js
var matrix = [
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
'00110000011000111111000110000000110000001111100000',
'00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000',
'00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000',
'00111111111000111111000110000000110000010000010000',
'00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000',
'00110000011000110000000110000000110000010000010000',
'00110000011000111111000111111000111111001111100000',
'00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000']


Array.prototype.scale_horizontal = function(factor) {
   var matrix=this;
   var new_matrix=new_matrix(matrix.length, matrix[0].length*factor, 0)
   for (var y=0; y<matrix.length; y++) {
    for (var x=0; x<matrix[y].length; x++) {
     // no idea
    }
   }

}



function new_matrix(rows, cols, value) {
 var arr = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  arr.push([]);
  arr[i].push(new Array(cols));
  for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++) arr[i][j] = value;
 };return arr;
}
```

So I would be super thankful about some code ideas because I have no clue how to continue coding this function.

Thanks a lot in advance, jonas

Comment: Is the logic 'always start with two 00 and then multiply the same number chunks by the factor` ? What about non-integer numbers? Error? Round up? Round down? WIll you always start from the first 2d matrix, or should multiple transformations be able to work after eachother?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it all into one function:

```
function scaleHorizontal(matrix, factor) {
    var scaledMatrix = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        var row = '';
        for(var j = 0; j <= matrix[i].length - 1; j += (1 / factor)) {
            row += matrix[i][Math.round(j)];
        }
        scaledMatrix.push(row);
    }
    return scaledMatrix;
}
```

Example output:

```
> scaleHorizontal(matrix, 0.25)
["0000000000000", 
 "0000101010110", 
 "0000001010000", 
 "0000001010000", 
 "0110101010000", 
 "0000001010000", 
 "0000001010000", 
 "0000101111110", 
 "0000000000000"]
```